# Installing pyarrow python causes command clang fail with exit status code 1 on mac 10.15

Tags: python, pip, clang, pyarrow

I have to install `pyarrow`. I am installing using `pip install pyarrow` but it is causing `clang` to fail. logs are

```
 error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic 
-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include -
I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework
/Versions/8.5/Headers -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -
Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -
Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -
Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort 
-I/usr/local/include 
-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include 
-I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include 
-I/Users/riteek/work/gojek/asgard/spikes/litmus-reporting/scipy-spike/venv/include 
-I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common 
-Ibuild/src.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath 
-Ibuild/src.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common 
-Ibuild/src.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: It seems to be trying to install numpy from source, instead of using the binary wheel packages. Does installing numpy by itself work?

Comment: I am able to install numpy using pip
```pip install numpy

Collecting numpy
 Using cached numpy-1.19.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy-1.19.4`
```

Comment: Can you post the full log? It should normally not build pyarrow from source but install the wheel.

Comment: We don't yet have pyarrow wheels for Python 3.9

Comment: @joris what is the alternative to install pyarrow, basically I want to install panda_gbq but that is failing while installing pyarrow.

Comment: Either use Python 3.8 for now (3.9 is really new, not all packages yet have newly built binaries ready), or use conda to install from conda-forge (https://conda-forge.org/)